# Internet connection is so bad on my linux mint, but good on windows 7 and windows xp and on mobile, why?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, connection, internet, linux-mint

I dual booted my xp, installing linux mint, My connection is so bad on my linux mint, but good on windows 7 and windows xp and on mobile.

**[speedtest.net](http://www.speedtest.net/) results on my linux mint 12**

```
Ping: 200ms
Download speed: 4.08 Mbps
Upload speed: 0.08 Mbps
```

All the websites are opening fast on my mint but some of them are not opening the right way, and some websites are not opening at all. I haven't been able to open SO this week. Now SO is opening as normal

**This is how github is opening**

[image]

**This is how youtube is opening:**

[image]

Do you know why I'm having this error? I don't have any antivirus, i am using default firewall settings, i have apache python django php ruby java and some stuff installed. But i don't think this is the cause.

I tried google chrome and firefox and this issue is on both browsers. I didn't have this issue last month. any guess? My isp cannot help me coz he's a windows guy and he's only responsible for fixing networking errors, not personal problems.

Comment: I tried deleting my cache and history, everything, didn't fix it :(

Comment: 4 days ago, i wasn't able to open google, now facebook don't open as it normally does, i can't download gems for my ror apps... please take a wild guess, just a wild wild guess on what may be causing the problem so i can fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a DNS issue. What are your settings in `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Try using OpenDNS servers: `208.67.222.222` and `208.67.220.220`

Comment: in my `/etc/resolv.conf` i see this:
`# Generated by NetworkManager`
`nameserver 192.168.1.1`

Comment: do i replace `192.168.1.1` with `208.67.222.222` and `208.67.220.220`?

Comment: Put each DNS server on a separate line. `nameserver 208.67.222.222` and `nameserver 208.67.220.220`.

Comment: slightly slower than the normal dns, but WORKED!!! WOOOOOOOOOORKED! one more question, is there any limitations for open dns? bandwidth usage? speed limit? anything like that?

Comment: OpenDNS is one of many free public DNS services. I use it on a day-to-day basis. It's generally accepted that ISP DNS servers are not the most reliable systems in the world.

Comment: is google public dns better than opendns? just asking coz google is behind it

Comment: Google Public DNS should be faster than OpenDNS, and has some tricks to try to resolve domains to geographically-close addresses (something that the global Google Public DNS and OpenDNS servers will be at a disadvantage relative to your ISP's local DNS servers, because upstream authoritative DNS servers can better guess your location that way).  OpenDNS also performs the cheap and offensive "return crap instead of NXDOMAIN" trick.  Granted, if you run your own `dnsmasq` you can work around that, but it's still pretty grating to me.

Comment: @ephemient Ok then, I'll use google dns :)

Answer (score 1):

A wild guess why your github opens like that, maybe you have javascript disabled on your browser...maybe not because you tried two browsers...

check ping www.github.com, is there any packet loss. Run it for a long time, maybe 3-4 mins and see how many packets are lost.

check your drivers on Linux for the wireless device(if you are on wifi). I am not familiar with mint so cannot tell you exactly how to do that. Google for a right driver.

Comment: javascript is enabled on google chrome and firefox, sorry for not mentioning that in my question :)

Comment: @user, yeah figured that as you are using two browsers, unlikely. But check my edited answer, hope something works out for you :)

Comment: how do i check the ping loss of a specific website? is there a tool or a web app for that? and yes, i am on wifi

Comment: i'm using [pingtest](http://www.pingtest.net/) and it says `couldn't connect to the server, a firewall might be blocking it or the server might be having issues.` Could it be a firewall problem?

Comment: @user sorry for late reply, but seems you got it working :) cool.